# Series of input, where’s the largest and the second largest?

Tags: java

I can get the program to output:

Enter a series of positive integers (-1 to stop):
Enter number #1: 5
Enter number #2: 6
Enter number #3: 8
Enter number #4: 74
Enter number #5: 75
Enter number #6: -1

But I can not get it to stop in -1 and it can not display the Largest and second largest number, can someone explain me where is the error?

```
 public static void main (String [] args){
    int number = 0;
    int i = 1;
    int largest = 0;
    int largest2 = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a series of positive integers (-1 to stop): ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (number >= 0) {
       System.out.print("Enter number #" + i++ + ": ");
       number = sc.nextInt();
    }
    number = sc.nextInt();
    largest2 = number;

    for (int i1 = 2; i1 < number; i1++) {
       number = sc.nextInt();
       if (number > largest) {
          largest = number;
       }
       if (largest2 > number) {
          argest2 = number;
       }
    }
    sc.close();
    System.out.println("The largest number entered is:" + largest);
    System.out.println("The second largest number entered is : " + largest);
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you taking way too many inputs than required?

Comment: Try using an array, you are just re-instancing your number variable with each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of bugs. To begin with, are you printing the same variable twice?
Following is a code to achieve the largest and second largest without storing input in array.

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    int number = 0, largest = 0, secondLargest = 0, count = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter number #"+ count++ +": ");
        number = scanner.nextInt();
        secondLargest = Math.max(secondLargest, number);
        if(largest < number) {
            secondLargest = largest;
            largest = number;
        }
    } while(number >= 0);
    System.out.println("The largest number entered is: "+largest);
    System.out.println("The second largest number entered is: "+secondLargest);

    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment if you need an explanation on it.

Answer (score 0):

Some Considerations

1. Consider admitting that you need help with your homework.
2. Consider designing the program before you write it.

Design:

1. Get some numbers, stop when you get -1.
2. After stopping, sort the numbers.
3. After sorting, display the top two.

Sorting every time a number is entered is terrible.

Design Considerations:

1. Don't use an array, you are not a clown.
2. Store the numbers in a Set.  This will remove duplicates.
3. Create a list after the user enters -1.  AddAll from the Set to the list.
4. Sort the list from biggest to smallest.
5. Display the first two elements.

Answer (score 0):

You're program isn't stuck at -1, but instead it waits for another input, because you call `sc.nextInt()` again after you get out of the while.

I think the easiest way is to just write all the numbers in a list until you reach -1, then go through the list and search for the largest and the second largest.

Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 0;
    int numberCount = 1;
    System.out.println("Enter a series of positive integers (-1 to stop): ");

    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (number >= 0) {
        System.out.print("Enter number #" + numberCount++ + ": ");
        number = sc.nextInt();
        numbers.add(number);
    }

    int largest = numbers.get(0);
    int secondLargest = numbers.get(0);
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        Integer currentNumber = numbers.get(i);
        if (currentNumber >= largest) {
            secondLargest = largest;
            largest = currentNumber;
        } else if (currentNumber > secondLargest) {
            secondLargest = currentNumber;
        }
        if (currentNumber < smallest) {
            smallest = currentNumber;
        }
    }

    sc.close();
    System.out.println("The largest number entered is:" + largest);
    System.out.println("The second largest number entered is : " + secondLargest);
}
```